# A python script works at command line, but when the exact same script is called from php, nothing is returned

Tags: php, python, exec

I am trying to call a python script from php:

```py
python test_upload.py test.xlsm
```

The python command works at windows command line. The script processes 4 rows of data.  But when it is called in php it does not appear to be processed at all.

```php
$result = exec($cmd, $output, $status);
```

The *$result* is null, and *$output* has 0 items.

Comment: check the current directory. It may be different.

Comment: Where is your php running ? Maybe exec is (commonly) disabled ? Check it works with something else.